# map/filter/reduce with Array

Tags: javascript

I have a class with Array as a class member.  And I have many class functions that do something with each element of array:

```
function MyClass {
    this.data = new Array();
}

MyClass.prototype.something_to_do = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
        // do something with this.data[i]
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.another_thing_to_do = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
        // do something with this.data[i]
    }
}
```

If there any way to improve this code?  I'm searching something like 'map(), filter(), reduce()' in the functional languages:

```
MyClass.prototype.something_to_do = function() {
    this.data.map/filter/reduce = function(element) {       
    }
}
```

Any way to remove explicit for-loop.

Comment: I think it belongs on [**CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `map()` function in JavaScript. Have a look at the [MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
MyClass.prototype.something_to_do = function() {
  this.data = this.data.map( function( item ) { 
    // do something with item aka this.data[i]
    // and return the new version afterwards
    return item;
  } );
}
```

Accordingly there are `filter()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) and `reduce()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).